# Sending attachment to Skype for Business from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying to send an image attachment to Skype for Business from NodeJS. 
The code perfectly works for Skype - images are sent to Skype client from bot.

But it doesn't work for Skype for Business.

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
   .addAttachment({
       contentUrl: 'https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/images/faq-overview/botframework_overview_july.png',
       contentType: 'image/png',
       name: 'BotFrameworkOverview.png'
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skype for Business channel integration for Bot Framework is currently in developer preview state.

Send attachement in Skype for business is not supported yet, you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/Skype-For-Business-Bot-Framework/docs/overview#feature-support for all the features supportted currently.

And you can refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3208 on GitHub to monitor the status of this feature request.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there roadmap date defined somewhere? We are implementing a feature which requires attachments sent.

Comment: Currently, I think you can open a request issue on GitHub, which is easy for monitor and updating information. Also. the document online should be updated in time.